# Bootstrap toggle not responding

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel project where I created a dropdown toggle for someone to click and logout. I did it on my workstation and it works fine. When I tried to run it on my home desktop, it does not respond at all.

I did not change the imported css and js files. Why doesn't it work in the difference place when the code is the same?

My imports for reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>


    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

    <!-- TODO: Import using Mix -->
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/geniuscart/geniuscart.js') }}"></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- TODO: Import using Mix -->
    <!-- GeniusCart Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/geniuscart/geniuscart.css') }}">
    <!-- Icons -->
    <!-- Icofont -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/icofont/icofont.min.css') }}">
    <!-- FontAwesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: try to clear cache from browser click `ctrl + shift + R`

Comment: Open your browser devtools (usually f12 key) and disable cache.

Comment: It isn't clear but I am guessing `when I tried to run it` means you copied the code from a local Laravel site from one computer to another? If yes, is the project installed properly at the web server's docroot?  Are [directory permissions set up correctly](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8)? Anyway, start with some basic debugging - open your browser's devtools, check for errors on the console. Check the network tab - are the JS/CSS files being loaded OK?  Do the files really exist on disk, and where they're expected to be?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I did check on everything you mentioned and no sign of errors. I cloned this project through github in the proper way and everything works except the dropdown toggle is not responsive. Now I don't know if this is a browser version issue, since they both are running on latest version of chrome so I don't know. I noticed it's just strange. I noticed if I add a import (jquery or bootstrap ) to the blade file that has the issue, the problem resolves. But the imports should be carried forward in the source code. What gives?

Comment: Btw, disabling or clearing cache did not help in this case. I am out of options.

Comment: `add a import` - what does this mean?

Comment: It means when I add something like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUIyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
` then the problem resolves.

Comment: If you are trying to set up a Bootstrap nav without including Bootstrap JS/CSS, then clearly that is the reason it doesn't work. You'll have to debug how it ever worked on the first machine when you get back to it.  PS - not that it is related to this issue, but unless you like weird risky JS/CSS behaviour, I would suggest not using an alpha release!

Comment: @Don'tPanic Noted, but I am really eager to find out what causes it to work in workstation but not in my other machine. The source code does include imports for Bootstrap (with jquery) so I was shocked. What do you mean by alpha release?